# How to match "no" in a string using prxmatch but not "not"

Tags: regex, sas

I am pulling out survey participants comments from a dataset using prxmatch in SAS EG 7.1. There are a lot of comments that start with "No", it might just be no on its own or it might say no problems etc. I only want to filter these out if the string starts with "no", and not if "no" is contained elsewhere in the string so I have included the ^ metacharacter but I noticed some comments are being filtered out if they have "not" in them so I include \b after no for the word boundary however it is still filtering out strings that have "not" or "no" anywhere within the string.
Examples of what should match:
"No problems" "No"
Examples of what should NOT match:
"His name is STEVE not SPEVE" "I was mostly fine but I was not expecting to get a headache"

How do I stop this from happening? I've included my code, any help would be great.

```
data cclhd hnelhd islhd nbmlhd seslhd swslhd slhd wslhd mnclhd nnswlhd wnswlhd;
set work.schools_dataset;
where Comments ne " ";
if prxmatch ("m/^no\b|^nil|^none|^nop|all good|na|n\/a|n\.a/i",Comments) = 0 ;
keep ParticipantID FirstName Mobile VaxDate OperationID Venue Comments;
if operationid=108 then output work.cclhd;
else if operationid=109 then output work.hnelhd;
else if operationid=110 then output work.islhd;
else if operationid=111 then output work.nbmlhd;
else if operationid=113 then output work.seslhd;
else if operationid=114 then output work.swslhd;
else if operationid=115 then output work.slhd;
else if operationid=116 then output work.wslhd;
else if operationid=118 then output work.mnclhd;
else if operationid=120 then output work.nnswlhd;
else if operationid=122 then output work.wnswlhd;
```

run;

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, use: `r"\bno\b(?!not)"`

Comment: @MendelG are you able show me how you would include this in my code? Sorry, I'm quite new to coding and I'm just not sure what you mean without the full context. Thanks heaps

Comment: Try replacing `^no\b` with `\bno\b`. `^` matches start of string only. Else, try to check if there are other keywords in the unwelcome strings you get.

Comment: Thank you everyone who has answered. I've realised some of the other terms are matching where I don't want them to. For example 'na' was matching with 'name' as I hadn't used a boundary. I have fixed my code so that most of the terms are followed by \b and this has fixed my problem. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data cclhd hnelhd islhd nbmlhd seslhd swslhd slhd wslhd mnclhd nnswlhd wnswlhd;
set work.schools_dataset;
where Comments ne " ";
if prxmatch("/^no\b/i",comments) = 0;
keep ParticipantID FirstName Mobile VaxDate OperationID Venue Comments;
if operationid=108 then output work.cclhd;
else if operationid=109 then output work.hnelhd;
else if operationid=110 then output work.islhd;
else if operationid=111 then output work.nbmlhd;
else if operationid=113 then output work.seslhd;
else if operationid=114 then output work.swslhd;
else if operationid=115 then output work.slhd;
else if operationid=116 then output work.wslhd;
else if operationid=118 then output work.mnclhd;
else if operationid=120 then output work.nnswlhd;
else if operationid=122 then output work.wnswlhd;
```